# The shadow looks like a wave. How do I fix it?

Tags: materials, error, shadows, denoise, vector-mapping

[image]

I can't solve it in 3 hours...

Comment: hello, what shadow are your talking about? maybe share a simplified version of your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Try: rendering with cycles, checking meshes for inverted normals, checking for overlapping faces

Comment: Yes it can be denoiser (low samples), I haven't seen it this condition but who knows :) also in background seems to be curvy somehow. Please add some detail, as moon boots mentioned it is not clear what are you asking for, what is your setup for material, render, ... BTW what do you mean vector-mapping

Comment: Thank you! I have uploaded a simplified version. I am using cycle render. It's a wavy shadow on the bottom of the table, will it be okay if I add the number of samples?

Comment: The sample value was the problem. Please take a look at the shared files. Thank you so much everyone. too!

Comment: Great you solved it. BTW I dont see your files, in case you still want to let us inspect your file you have to paste given code into your question to share your file?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're talking about the floor under the table.  It looks like the denoiser doesn't have enough samples to give you an accurate representation of the shadow.

You can enable viewport denoising and draw a render region around the trouble area to watch it render and determine how many samples you'll need to get the desired result.

Comment: The sample value was the problem. Please take a look at the shared files. Thank you so much everyone. too!

Comment: Consider mark answer as accepted so others can  see it from main list. https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour